# i want fetch the year entries...in month wise

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name as p_visit_user now want all the year entries in month wise format

```
<?php

$wherecat1 = "`p_user_visit_status` = 'active' AND date(`p_user_visit_date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR_MONTH) ";
$catsql1 = $general->GetRows('*', 'p_user_visit', $wherecat1);
$catRes1 = mysql_num_rows($catsql1);
?>
```

Comment: please give more about your table structure

Comment: i created table name as p_user_visit in which i have 7 fields

Comment: p_user_visit_ip , p_user_visit_browser, p_user_visit_country ,p_user_visit_no ,p_user_visit_status,   p_user_visit_date

Comment: and i have fetch the number of values ids month vise of whole year

Comment: please set up schema in sqlfiddle..An let us know

Comment: PLease edit question with sample data and expected output